# ¿En tu región, se dice "No oigo" o "No escucho"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, diferencias-regionales

En México, aprendí a decir

> No oigo / no te oigo

cuando la persona habla muy bajito y no alcanzo a distinguir bien sus palabras.

Pero luego me di cuenta de que una peruana decía

> No escucho

¿Cuál es más común donde tú vives?

Comment: mmm en España lo de _no escucho_ se utiliza mucho, pero es incorrecto en este contexto: _Menos justificable es el empleo de escuchar en lugar de oír, para referirse simplemente a la acción de percibir un sonido a través del oído, sin que exista intencionalidad previa por parte del sujeto_ ([DPD en escuchar](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=EM6vahEKOD6LYmKQpP))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Colombia: Las dos formas.
- México: No oigo.
- Perú: No escucho.

Answer (score 4):

No sé si está relacionado con la región en sí o no, pero como hablante de catalán y castellano, uso ambos con algunas diferencias:

- "no oigo" cuando estoy dando a entender que no puedo oír lo que me están diciendo
- "no escucho" cuando digo que no estoy atendiendo a lo que me están diciendo